# R: How to turn a table of transaction-item pairs into a matrix of transactions x items?

Tags: r, data-visualization, data-mining

I have a data frame in R like this:

```
user1,A
user1,B
user2,A
user2,C
user2,C
user3,A
user4,C
```

How can I transform it into a table like this?

```
user1,1,1,0
user2,1,0,2
user3,1,0,0
user4,0,0,1
```

Actually my data has a time interval as the second column, which is the time passed between the user's first and current purchase. I want to do a matrix plot in which each line in the matrix is a line in the image (And each element a pixel).

(I can (kinda) do it with the arules package, exporting the original dataframe and importing it as transactions, but I think there must be a direct way to do this, without needing such a hack.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can just use `table()`

```
> table(df1)
#       V2
#V1      A B C
#  user1 1 1 0
#  user2 1 0 2
#  user3 1 0 0
#  user4 0 0 1
```

If you want to store this output as a new dataframe `df2`, this is one possibility:

```
df2 <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(df1))
```

**data**

```
df1 <- read.table(text="user1,A
                        user1,B
                        user2,A
                        user2,C
                        user2,C
                        user3,A
                        user4,C", header=F, sep=",")
```